# Visual Studio Docker Compose not build correctly the project

Tags: c#, .net, docker, visual-studio, docker-compose

I have a strange thing with my project that I do not understand.
At work we change the workflow, so now we have to dev all through Docker.
I started a new test API project in .Net 6, with a MySql DB, so I made it all with docker-compose to run in the same network.

I start my project with choosing `docker-compose` in the start projects' select menu, and all works fine. I can connect to my DB, make migrations, test endpoints with Insomnia.
The problem is, while I am developing, when I made new changes, if I run directly with `docker-compose`, new changes are not taken into account. I found that I have to run first the project by select my project, that is `Test.API`, stop it, select `docker compose` and run it again. And just then, my changes are here...

I tried to start build manually in the terminal, but that's not better, same thing here.
I am sure I missed something in configuration of Docker Compose, but after searching a while, I can't find it. And that workflow is pretty long, I'm convinced that is not normal workflow.
And of course, if I start only through my project, it does not connect to my DB, because they're not on the same network in Docker

So if someone can see what I missed or make wrong, I'm all hearing

Here is some of config

### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Test.API/Test.API.csproj", "Test.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Test.API/Test.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Test.API"
RUN dotnet build "Test.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.API.dll"]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  test.api:
    depends_on:
        - mysql-test
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}testapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Test.API/Dockerfile

  mysql-test:
    image: mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer

volumes:
    test-data: ~
```

### docker-compose.override.yml

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  test.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__ProjectDatabase=Server=mysql-test;Port=3306;Database=tests_db;Uid=testGuy;Pwd=essai;
    ports:
      - "80"
  
  mysql-test:
    container_name: mysql-test
    ports: 
        - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_pass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: tests_db
        MYSQL_USER: testGuy
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: essai
    volumes:
        - test-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

### docker-compose's launchSettings.json

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Docker Compose": {
      "commandName": "DockerCompose",
      "commandVersion": "1.0",
      "composeLaunchAction": "None",
      "composeLaunchServiceName": "test.api",
      "serviceActions": {
        "adminer": "StartWithoutDebugging",
        "mysql-test": "StartWithoutDebugging",
        "test.api": "StartDebugging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### appSettings.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ProjectDatabase": "Server=mysql-test;Port=3306;Database=tests_db;Uid=testGuy;Pwd=essai"
  },
  "JwtSettings": {
    "Secret": "",
    "ExpiryDays": 1,
    "Issuer": "Test",
    "Audience":  "Test"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

### Docker Desktop containers

[Docker desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvcIT.png)